# How to destructure newValue = value.value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is just trivia / curiosity as I stumble across this situation a number of times.

Is it possible to shorten/destructure the following types of assignments?

```
newValue = value.value
```

Naively, I tried `newValue = {value}` but it doesn't work, as that syntax is normally used to destructure variables from objects with the same key name.

Comment: It's possible to use destructuring, but it neither shortens nor simplifies the assignment.

Comment: looking at the answers below i would go for original syntax i.e. newValue = value.value. The answer's looks confusing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this syntax to destructure and rename the property, this will get the value from object and rename it to variable `newValue`

```
var {value: newValue} = value
```

```js
var value = {value: 5}

var {value: newValue} = value

console.log(newValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern) with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var value = { value: 42 },
    { value: newValue } = value;

console.log(newValue);
```

If not used as expression, like with `var`, `let` or `const`, you need parentheses to distinguish the braces from a block statement.

```js
var value = { value: 42 },
    newValue;

({ value: newValue } = value);

console.log(newValue);
```